# How to fix Dism error 14098?

Tags: windows-10, dism

Recently I got a very stubborn corruption on my Windows 10 installation. I noticed it because WMI queries to Win32_OptionalFeature hung indefinitely (only kept spawning hidden Werfaults that closed immidiately). Because of this "Programs and Features\Turn Windows Features on or off" doesn't load.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.


Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /checkhealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.10586.0

Image Version: 10.0.10586.0

The component store is repairable.
The operation completed successfully.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.10586.0

Image Version: 10.0.10586.0

[===========                20.0%                          ]

Error: 14098

The component store has been corrupted.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log

C:\WINDOWS\system32>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:WIM:F:\Sources\Install.wim:1 /LimitAccess

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.10586.0

Image Version: 10.0.10586.0

[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 14098

The component store has been corrupted.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

CBS.log

```
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  CBS    TI: --- Initializing Trusted Installer ---
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  CBS    TI: Last boot time: 2016-03-31 20:22:32.491
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  CBS    Starting TrustedInstaller initialization.
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  CBS    Ending TrustedInstaller initialization.
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  CBS    Starting the TrustedInstaller main loop.
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  CBS    TrustedInstaller service starts successfully.
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  CBS    No startup processing required, TrustedInstaller service was not set as autostart
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  CBS    Startup processing thread terminated normally
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  CBS    Starting TiWorker initialization.
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  CBS    Ending TiWorker initialization.
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  CBS    Starting the TiWorker main loop.
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  CBS    TiWorker starts successfully.
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  CBS    Universal Time is: 2016-03-31 18:42:38.816
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  CBS    Loaded Servicing Stack v10.0.10586.168 with Core: C:\WINDOWS\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10586.168_none_76587b40265ca57e\cbscore.dll
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  CSI    00000001@2016/3/31:18:42:38.820 WcpInitialize (wcp.dll version 0.0.0.6) called (stack @0x7fff64954699 @0x7fff65551248 @0x7fff6556150b @0x7ff67c342ee0 @0x7ff67c3438e1 @0x7fff87bbd533)
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  CBS    NonStart: Set pending store consistency check.
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  CBS    Session: 30509949_430630895 initialized by client DISM Package Manager Provider, external staging directory: (null)
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  CBS    Exec: Addsource called, Session: 30509949_430630895, Client: DISM Package Manager Provider, from GPO: No, Path: wim:F:\Sources\Install.wim:1
2016-03-31 20:42:39, Info                  CBS    Client specifies store corruption detect and repair.
2016-03-31 20:42:39, Info                  CBS    Exec: Session processing started.  Client: DISM Package Manager Provider, Session(Store Corruption Detect/Repair): 30509949_430630895
2016-03-31 20:42:39, Info                  CBS    Reboot mark set
2016-03-31 20:42:39, Info                  CBS    Winlogon: Registering for CreateSession notifications
2016-03-31 20:42:39, Info                  CBS    Winlogon: Loading SysNotify DLL
2016-03-31 20:42:39, Info                  CBS    Winlogon: Starting notify server 
2016-03-31 20:42:54, Info                  CBS    Repr: CBS Store check completes
2016-03-31 20:42:57, Info                  CSI    00000002@2016/3/31:18:42:57.491 PopulateComponentFamiliesKey - Begin
2016-03-31 20:42:59, Error                 CSI    00000003 (F) Unable to parse version scope string: [l:4]"NonS"
[gle=0x80004005]
2016-03-31 20:42:59, Error                 CSI    00000004@2016/3/31:18:42:59.862 (F) base\wcp\identity\id_authority_helpers.cpp(1587): Error STATUS_SXS_INVALID_IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE originated in function Windows::Identity::Rtl::Implementation::id_AddBuiltinToBuiltinAttributes expression: fParsedOK
[gle=0x80004005]
2016-03-31 20:42:59, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CBS.log to WER report.
2016-03-31 20:42:59, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160329171050.cab to WER report.
2016-03-31 20:42:59, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160323195513.cab to WER report.
2016-03-31 20:42:59, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160310133217.cab to WER report.
2016-03-31 20:42:59, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160216081530.cab to WER report.
2016-03-31 20:42:59, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160201075759.cab to WER report.
2016-03-31 20:42:59, Info                  CBS    Not able to add current session file to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-03-31 20:42:59, Info                  CBS    Not able to add pending.xml to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-03-31 20:42:59, Info                  CBS    Not able to add pending.xml.bad to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-03-31 20:42:59, Info                  CBS    Not able to add SCM.EVM to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Error                 CSI    00000005 (F) STATUS_SXS_INVALID_IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE #525112# from Windows::Identity::Rtl::Implementation::CRtlIdentityAuthority::IRtlIdentityAuthority_Parse(flags = 0, string = [l:158]"Microsoft-Windows-IIS-BPA-Deployment, Culture=neutral, Version=10.0.10586.0, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=amd64, versionScope=NonS[gle=0xd0150016]
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Error                 CSI    00000006@2016/3/31:18:43:00.310 (F) base\wcp\componentstore\versionedindex.cpp(1021): Error STATUS_SXS_COMPONENT_STORE_CORRUPT originated in function ComponentStore::CRawStoreLayout::PopulateComponentFamiliesKey expression: (null)
[gle=0x80004005]
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CBS.log to WER report.
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160329171050.cab to WER report.
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160323195513.cab to WER report.
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160310133217.cab to WER report.
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160216081530.cab to WER report.
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20160201075759.cab to WER report.
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Not able to add current session file to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Not able to add pending.xml to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Not able to add pending.xml.bad to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Not able to add SCM.EVM to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Failed to get CSI system store [HRESULT = 0x80073712 - ERROR_SXS_COMPONENT_STORE_CORRUPT]
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    CSI store consistency check fails. [HRESULT = 0x80073712 - ERROR_SXS_COMPONENT_STORE_CORRUPT]
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Failed to load component store [HRESULT = 0x80073712 - ERROR_SXS_COMPONENT_STORE_CORRUPT]
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Failed to get CSI store. [HRESULT = 0x80073712 - ERROR_SXS_COMPONENT_STORE_CORRUPT]
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Failed to get CSI Store. [HRESULT = 0x80073712 - ERROR_SXS_COMPONENT_STORE_CORRUPT]
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Failed to get CSI session store. [HRESULT = 0x80073712 - ERROR_SXS_COMPONENT_STORE_CORRUPT]
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Failed to check CSI store. [HRESULT = 0x80073712 - ERROR_SXS_COMPONENT_STORE_CORRUPT]
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Ensure CBS corruption flag is clear
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Ensure WCP corruption flag is clear
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    
=================================
Checking System Update Readiness.


Summary:
Operation: Detect and Repair 
Operation result: 0x80073712
Last Successful Step: CBS store detection completes.
Total Detected Corruption:  0
    CBS Manifest Corruption:    0
    CBS Metadata Corruption:    0
    CSI Manifest Corruption:    0
    CSI Metadata Corruption:    0
    CSI Payload Corruption: 0
Total Repaired Corruption:  0
    CBS Manifest Repaired:  0
    CSI Manifest Repaired:  0
    CSI Payload Repaired:   0
    CSI Store Metadata refreshed:   False

Total Operation Time: 21 seconds.

2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    CheckSur: hrStatus: 0x80073712 [ERROR_SXS_COMPONENT_STORE_CORRUPT], download Result: 0x0 [S_OK]
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Count of times corruption detected: 0
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Seconds between initial corruption detections: -1
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Seconds between corruption and repair: -1
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    SQM: Package change report datapoints not populated because SQM is not initialized or not running online.
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Failed to run Detect and repair. [HRESULT = 0x80073712 - ERROR_SXS_COMPONENT_STORE_CORRUPT]
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Reboot mark cleared
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Winlogon: Simplifying Winlogon CreateSession notifications
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Winlogon: Deregistering for CreateSession notifications
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Exec: Processing complete, session(Corruption Repairing): 30509949_430630895 [HRESULT = 0x80073712 - ERROR_SXS_COMPONENT_STORE_CORRUPT]
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Error                 CBS    Session: 30509949_430630895 failed to perform store corruption detect and repair operation. [HRESULT = 0x80073712 - ERROR_SXS_COMPONENT_STORE_CORRUPT]
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Session: 30509949_430630895 finalized. Reboot required: no [HRESULT = 0x80073712 - ERROR_SXS_COMPONENT_STORE_CORRUPT]
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  CBS    Failed to FinalizeEx using worker session [HRESULT = 0x80073712]
```

DISM.log (start trimmed to fit the post length limit)

```
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=2240 TID=5832 Current image session is [ONLINE] - CTransmogManager::GetMode
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=2240 TID=5832 Audit Mode: [No] - CTransmogManager::Initialize
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=2240 TID=5832 GetProductType: ProductType = [WinNT] - CTransmogManager::GetProductType
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=2240 TID=5832 Product Type: [WinNT] - CTransmogManager::Initialize
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=2240 TID=5832 Product Type ServerNT : [No] - CTransmogManager::Initialize
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Got the collection of providers. Now enumerating them to build the command table.
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: DISM Log Provider
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: OSServices
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: DISM Package Manager
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: DISM Package Manager.
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: MsiManager
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: MsiManager.
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: IntlManager
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: IntlManager.
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: IBSManager
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: DriverManager
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: DriverManager.
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: DISM Unattend Manager
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: DISM Unattend Manager.
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: SmiManager
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: AppxManager
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: AppxManager.
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: ProvManager
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: ProvManager.
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: AssocManager
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: AssocManager.
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: GenericManager
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: GenericManager.
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: OfflineSetupManager
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: Edition Manager
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: Edition Manager.
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Getting Provider DISM Package Manager - CDISMProviderStore::GetProvider
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Provider has previously been initialized.  Returning the existing instance. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=2240 TID=5832 Processing the top level command token(cleanup-image). - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ValidateCmdLine
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=2240 TID=5832 Attempting to route to appropriate command handler. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2016-03-31 20:42:38, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=2240 TID=5832 Routing the command... - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2016-03-31 20:42:39, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=2240 TID=5832 CBS session options=0x28100! - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=2240 TID=2172  Error in operation: (null) (CBS HRESULT=0x80073712) - CCbsConUIHandler::Error
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=2240 TID=5832 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x80073712)
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=2240 TID=5832 Failed processing package changes with session option CbsSessionOptionRepairStoreCorruption - CDISMPackageManager::RestoreHealth(hr:0x80073712)
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=2240 TID=5832 Failed to restore the image health. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ProcessCmdLine_CleanupImage(hr:0x80073712)
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=2240 TID=5832 Failed while processing command cleanup-image. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x80073712)
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=2240 TID=5832 Further logs for online package and feature related operations can be found at %WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Error                 DISM   DISM.EXE: DISM Package Manager processed the command line but failed. HRESULT=80073712
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Found the PE Provider.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Finalizing the servicing provider(DISM Package Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=2240 TID=5832 Finalizing CBS core. - CDISMPackageManager::Finalize
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Disconnecting Provider: DISM Package Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Finalizing the servicing provider(MsiManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Disconnecting Provider: MsiManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Finalizing the servicing provider(IntlManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Disconnecting Provider: IntlManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Finalizing the servicing provider(IBSManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Disconnecting Provider: IBSManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Finalizing the servicing provider(DriverManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Disconnecting Provider: DriverManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Finalizing the servicing provider(DISM Unattend Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Disconnecting Provider: DISM Unattend Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Finalizing the servicing provider(SmiManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Disconnecting Provider: SmiManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Finalizing the servicing provider(AppxManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Disconnecting Provider: AppxManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Finalizing the servicing provider(ProvManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Disconnecting Provider: ProvManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Finalizing the servicing provider(AssocManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Disconnecting Provider: AssocManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Finalizing the servicing provider(GenericManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Disconnecting Provider: GenericManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Finalizing the servicing provider(OfflineSetupManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Disconnecting Provider: OfflineSetupManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Finalizing the servicing provider(Edition Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Disconnecting Provider: Edition Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Releasing the local reference to OSServices. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Disconnecting Provider: OSServices - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2240 TID=5832 Releasing the local reference to DISMLogger.  Stop logging. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=200 TID=620 Closing session event handle 0x16c - CDISMManager::CloseImageSession
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Image session has been closed. Reboot required=no.
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: <----- Ending Dism.exe session ----->
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=200 TID=620 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=200 TID=620 Disconnecting Provider: FolderManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2016-03-31 20:43:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=200 TID=620 Releasing the local reference to DISMLogger.  Stop logging. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
```

Comment: Are you unable to update Windows 10, because, you are not on the current build. `10.0.10586.163` is the current build.  You will need to download a `10586.0` which will be tough since they don't exist, and direct DISM to the install.vim, to actually run the command.

Comment: Forgot to add that restarting does not help. WindowsUpdateClient keeps failing to install updates, so running an old build checks out.

Comment: Have you tried loading the current Version 1511 .ISO and just doing an in-place upgrade/installation, at this stage outside of using an external component store, you can't runt he command your trying to use but the source **must** be the current version which will be tough since your not using the current build.

Comment: Actually I was using the wrong version of the image. I do actually have the 10586.0 iso, but dism failed with it in the exact same way. Looking at the logs it doesn't even get to load the image, looks like something other than the component store is corrupted.

Comment: Have you run a `chkdsk` to check the disks yet?

Comment: Yes, it found nothing. I believe a botched automatic update caused the problem. So much for being seamless.

Comment: run the DISM command without the /source paramater and let Windows download the files

Comment: Running with no source doesn't change anything.

Comment: Using WinDbg I found that everything trying to access the CSI store crashes with [HRESULT = 0x80073712 - ERROR_SXS_COMPONENT_STORE_CORRUPT]
Whoever wrote the error handling just went "eh, whatever, she'll be right" and added an infinite retry, hoping the problem would go away by itself.

Comment: repair Windows 10 via Inplace upgrade: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried many different approaches to fix the problem, but unfortunately some system files were corrupted.

The easiest fix was a Windows 10 inplace upgrade, as people in comments have suggested.